# Nginx allow post to specific location and deny to the rest

Tags: nginx, post, nginx-ingress

I'm facing some issues while trying to allow POST to specific location and deny the rest of the locations in nginx ingress controller.

I want to open the POST option to 2 different path:

`/api/v1/user/something`

`/api/v1/usersomething`

My current configurations:

```
server-snippet: |-
  add_header Allow "GET, HEAD" always;
  location /api/v1/ {
    allow all;
  }
  if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
      return 405;
  }
  location /health {
    access_log off;
    return 200 "healthy\n";
  }
```

Still, for every `/api/` location, I get the return code as 405.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: doesn't solve my issue :-(

Comment: Is this the [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) or the [nginx-ingress](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/) controller you are referring to?

Both of these snippet annotations require a prefix, I assume you're using the Kubernetes community ingress controller. In this case, the annotation would be `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`.

If you could paste the entire ingress manifest it would help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add something like this?

```
add_header              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

Comment: not working :-(
`location /api/v1/ {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    }
`
response:
`HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2020 14:17:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 163
Connection: keep-alive
Allow: GET, HEAD
`

Comment: @israelshenkar check the Nginx logs, you should examine the url the server received and where it tried to use it. maybe your location doesn't work.